# Поиск двух одинаковых элементов в IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, алгоритм

Есть метод, возвращающий большое количество элементов

```
static IEnumerable<double> MultiplicatedNumberSequence(long n, long a, long beta, long m)
        {
            for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                a = (beta * a) % m;
                yield return (double)a / m;
            }
        }
```

Количество элементов n = 2^31. Метод возвращает 2^31 степени элементов. a равняется остатку от деления на m, значит a ограничено и целое. Значит если взять больше чем 2^31 элементов среди них найдутся одинаковые. Элементов слишком много чтобы загнать все в массив или отсортировать. Как можно быстро (не ожидая часы и дни) найти в коллекции два одинаковых элемента, их индексы и разность между индексами двух одинаковых элементов? Никак не могу придумать адекватный метод. Загнать в List<> не выходит, не хватает памяти, а брать элементы по порядку и сравнивать с оставшимися самоубийство, потому что количество итераций будет (2^31)^2 = 2^62.

Comment: Интересная задача. Даже стандартная реализация Enumerable.Distinct использует Set для хранения уникальных элементов, т.е. потребует памяти. В порядке бреда: загнать последовательность в БД и сделать select distinct.

Comment: А каково значение `m` примерно? Просто метод возвращает ровно `m` уникальных значений: `0/m`, `1/m`, ..., `(m-1)/m`, т.к. `0 <= a < m`, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: метод возвращает n элементов ограниченных числом m. Значит если n>m то в коллекции есть полюбому одинаковые элементы. Точнее переменная а ограничена M а метод возвращает a/m.

Comment: Именно. И каков же порядок величины `m`? 10, 100, 1000, .., 2^30?

Comment: m постоянная равна 2^31 степени

Answer (score 7):

По всей видимости, с приведенной последовательностью это быстро сделать не получится - получив на вход `IEnumerable<double>` можно сделать очень немногое.

Однако, если параметры последовательности известны, к этой задаче можно подойти аналитически, без генерирования самой последовательности!

Ваша последовательность, если ее не делить на 0 - это же `a * beta^i % m`.

Если beta взаимно просто с m - то, как следует из малой теоремы Ферма,

```
beta ^ (φ(m) - 1) % m = 1
```

Иными словами, цикл всегда есть, начинается он с первого элемента, а его длина должна быть делителем `φ(m) - 1`, где `φ` - функция Эйлера.

Теперь что если beta не является взаимно простой с m - тогда их общий множитель, оказавшись внутри a, уже не "покинет" эту переменную. У цикла появляется префикс (он начинается не с 1).

Таким образом, критерий начала цикла - тот факт, что `gcd(a, m) = gcd(a*beta, m)`, где gcd - наибольший общий делитель:

```
// Алгоритм Евклида
int gcd(int a, int b) {
  while (b > 0) {
    var c = a % b;
    a = b;
    b = c;
  }
  return a;
}

int first = 0;
while (gcd(a, m) != gcd(a*beta, m)) {
  a = (a * beta) % m;
  first++;
}
```

В принципе, знания первого элемента цикла достаточно чтобы найти его повтор за разумное время. Но если есть желание поковыряться, можно пойти дальше. Теперь можно сделать эквивалентное преобразование оставшейся последовательности, сократив `a` и `m` на их НОД - это не изменит длину цикла, но позволит воспользоваться формулой:

```
int d = gcd(a, m);
m /= d;
a /= d;
```

Теперь осталось перебрать делители `φ(m) - 1` и найти среди них длину цикла (к примеру, при помощи алгоритма быстрого возведения в степень). Тут проще всего начать с заведомо подходящей длины `φ(m) - 1` и пытаться разделить ее на все простые делители меньшие квадратного корня, каждый раз проверяя цикл при помощи быстрого возведения в степень.

Итоговое время работы - O(M^½ * log M), то есть время порядка 2^21. В специальном случае когда M - степень двойки, все еще сильнее упрощается и остается только O((log M)^2) (а зная заранее что M - степень двойки, можно алгоритм написать совсем просто, обойдясь даже без алгоритма Евклида).

Comment: Очень объемный интересный ответ, спасибо

Comment: мне вот интересно хоть один из этих 2 ответов поможет человеку который из гугла сюда попадёт?)

Answer (score 2):

Обновление: Функция будет периодической с самого начала лишь для случая, когда `beta` и `m` не взаимно просты. Для изучения периода лучше возвращать из функции `MultiplicatedNumberSequence` не преобразованный `double`, а число `a`. Судя по всему, при этом у текущего члена последовательности возрастает НОД с `m`. Поэтому для пропускания «префикса» сделаем так:

```
static long gcd(long a, long b)
{
    while (a != 0 && b != 0)
    {
        var temp = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = temp;
    }
    return a + b;
}

long prevgcd = -1;
var seq = MultiplicatedNumberSequence(...)
            .SkipWhile(v => prevgcd != (prevgcd = gcd(v, m)));
```

Оставшийся «хвост» последовательности периодичен, начиная с начала, так что можно просто запомнить первый элемент и прокрутить до его повторения. Впрочем, это по сути совпадает с методом @Pavel Mayorov, изложенным в другом ответе.

---

Классический метод — «заяц и черепаха». Вы пробегаете последовательность дважды, первый раз перепрыгивая через один элемент, второй следуя подряд за всеми элементами, и сравниваете их.

```
var seq = MultiplicatedNumberSequence(...);

using (var tortoise = seq.GetEnumerator())
using (var hare = seq.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (true)
    {
        // продвигаем первый обход на шаг
        if (!tortoise.MoveNext())
            break;
        // а второй на два
        if (!hare.MoveNext() || !hare.MoveNext())
            break;
        if (hare.Current != tortoise.Current)
            continue;
        // если вы тут, вы нашли повторяющиеся значения
        // делайте с ними что хотите
        // например, вы можете завести счётчик и подсчитать индексы
    }
}
```

Литература: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare (там есть и другие методы).

---

Поскольку вы сравниваете *действительные* числа, возможно, сравнение типа `a != b` следует заменить на `Math.Abs(b - a) > eps`.

---

Это работает для случая последовательности (*x*<sub>*n*</sub>), вычисляемой по правилу *x*<sub>*k*</sub> = *f*(*x*<sub>*k* − 1</sub>) для обратимой функции *f*.

Почему этот алгоритм работает? Пускай у нас для некоторых *k*, *m* выполняется *x*<sub>*k*</sub> = *x*<sub>*k* + *m*</sub>. Применяя *f* в обратную сторону, получим *x*<sub>*k* − 1</sub> = *x*<sub>*k* + *m* − 1</sub>, ..., *x*<sub>0</sub> = *x*<sub>*m*</sub>. Отсюда *x*<sub>0</sub> = *x*<sub>*m*</sub> = *x*<sub>2‌*m*</sub>. Значит, минимальный цикл найдётся, когда «заяц» будет на 2‌*m*, а черепаха на *m*.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39254/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd------ienumerable).

Answer (score 0):

### Особый алгоритм для случая, когда `m` - степень простого числа

*Данный алгоритм работает со сгенерированной последовательностью, не зная значений ее параметров.*

Если `beta` делится на простое число - то последовательность быстро закончится серией нулей. Если `beta` не делится на него - то последовательность циклическая.

Ну и плюс так как последовательность конечная - она может закончиться раньше чем это случится. Больше вариантов нет.

Зная это, можно написать алгоритм, где эти варианты будут проверены:

```
var seq = MultiplicatedNumberSequence(...).GetEnumerator();

const double eps = 1e-10;
double firstElement = 0;
int first = -1, second = -1;

using (seq as IDisposable) {
  for (int i=1; seq.MoveNext(); i++) {
    if (Math.Abs(seq.Current) < eps) { // Достигли нуля - дальше будут только они
      first = i;
      second = i+1;
      break;
    }
    if (i == 1) 
      firstElement = seq.Current;
    else if (Math.Abs(seq.Current - firstElement) < eps) { // Цикл замкнулся
      first = 1;
      second = i;
      break;
    }
  }
}

// Выход алгоритма: индексы совпадающих элементов - first и second.
```

Comment: То же будет по идее при замене 2 на любое простое число. Если `m = p^k`, то (1) если `beta` делится на `p`, последовательность выродится в нули, (2) если `beta` не делится на `p`, последовательность периодическая.

Comment: @VladD угу, так и есть